# print arbitrary amount of digits of float

Tags: python, algorithm, floating-point, square-root, newtons-method

How can I print more than about 10 digits of a `float` in python? Right now, when do

`print sqr_newton(10, 3, 0.001)` (where sqr_newton is newton's algorithm for square roots; returns a float)

it only gives so many digits after the decimal place... how can I get more?

Comment: Do you really mean "print", or rather "compute with"? You can print digits until you're blue in the face, but the standard float only has a small number of actually stored digits, so the information beyond that is meaningless.

Comment: first "compute with" then "print" them

Comment: In that case you'll need an arbitrary precision float.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the standard precision for floats in python.

For arbitrary precision, you can use the [bigfloat](http://packages.python.org/bigfloat/) package.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what operating system you are using but bigfloat requires that the MPFR and GMP libraries already exist on your computer. It may not be easy to use on Windows.

There are two other multiple precision libraries available that support Windows:

1) [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) which is written in pure Python and is stable and well documented.

2) [gmpy2](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) which is currently under active development. The next release should have a stable API. (Famous last words...)

If bigfloat works for you, great! It is a well-designed and documented package.

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy2 and have helped with mpmath.

Comment: Have either been tested on Heroku or Google App Engine?